# How to return a result of dynamic query where returned number of columns are also dynamic?

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql

We have function that generate dynamic query which uses [`crosstab`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html#TABLEFUNC-FUNCTIONS) function resulting in result set with dynamic number of columns. We tried using `RETURN QUERY` with `RETURNS SETOF RECORD` for this, but this gives me following error.

```
ERROR: materialize mode required, but it is not allowed in this context ... Error at RETURN QUERY
```

We took a look at the docs for [materialize mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-c.html), it seems we need to write some C code to do this, which is not possible in managed Postgres services

Simplified version of the above mentioned function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION app_public.incentive_per_line_report(p_from_date DATE, p_to_date DATE)
  RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
DECLARE
  ...
BEGIN
 
 -- Generating dynamic query string
 -- using crosstab which creates a result set with variable number of columns
 ...

 RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('%s',v_dynamic_query);

END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
STRICT
STABLE;
```